# Script Doesn't Work In rc.local

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, users, echo

I have a shell script that is supposed to send me a message with this command:

```
echo 'The user "Janet" has logged in' | write gilbert pts/0
```

If I run it, it does print the string. But if I put it in rc.local, it doesn't work.

Is there any way to fix this? Or is there a different approach to this problem?

Any answers are highly appreciated.

Comment: Why would you write to pts/0? How do you know what it will be pointing to when rc.local is run?

Comment: @muru I thought about your suggestion, and that is probably the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/etc/rc.local runs as the last step of startup. Nobody is logged in yet at this time, so when it checks to see if pts/0 belongs to gilbert, it doesn't, and the write fails.